# Cropping image for thumbnail failed

Tags: php, image, crop

I have an image like below:

[image: image1]

I am trying to create a thumbnail out of it which should display like below. As you can see, the second image is much smaller but it hasn't only been resized, the main portion of the image has been zoomed in a little to emphasize the frame.

[image: image2]

I have tried a number of image resizing/cropping solutions found in other questions on here but they seem to only resize the image and not actually crop out the portion I need.

I've tried a bunch of functions while using imagefromjpeg() etc. but failed thusfar.

An example of something I have tried:

```
$target_width  = 340;
$target_height = 270;
$new_img = @imagecreatetruecolor($target_width, $target_height);

$width_ratio  = $target_width  / $img_width;
$height_ratio = $target_height / $img_height;
if($width_ratio > $height_ratio) {
  $resized_width  = $target_width;
  $resized_height = $img_height * $width_ratio;
} else {
  $resized_height = $target_height;
  $resized_width  = $img_width * $height_ratio;
}

$resized_width  = round($resized_width);
$resized_height = round($resized_height);


$offset_width  = round(($target_width  - $resized_width) / 2);
$offset_height = round(($target_height - $resized_height) / 2);

$imgCopyRes = @imagecopyresampled($new_img, $src_img, $offset_width, $offset_height, 0, 0, $resized_width, $resized_height, $img_width, $img_height);
```

Comment: What is the point of creating a routine for this specific image? I have to assume you want to make more than one thumbnail, and not all those photo's should be trimmed in the same way? Or are you looking for some kind of AI software that will zoom in on the most important object in the photo?

Comment: Doesn't really have to be a routine, trimming a bit off the top and a bit off the bottom should be enough i think

Comment: "trimming at bit" is just too vague to create code from. You have to be very specific. The code you have seems to trim equal amounts off the top and the bottom, which is clearly not what you want (I haven't tested the code, but it looks like that's what it does). So how much do you want to trim from the top and how much from the bottom? 60% top, 40% bottom? You can use the the code you have, and just manipulate the `$offset_height`. For 60/40 it goes like this: `$offset_height = round(0.6 * ($target_height - $resized_height));` Just vary the 0.6 untill it does what you want.